# Can I use bash commands on Windows 10 for example by using VBA macros?

Tags: windows-10, bash, vba, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there possibility to use Linux command line tools in Windows 10? Namely, I mostly work on Ubuntu with `bash` and I have done some useful script to compute things on CSV-files, for example by `awk`. And sometimes `grep` is useful for my tasks. I was thinking if I can use them in Excel by making a new VBA script that calls Linux subsystem for Windows 10, does the work and gets a results to Windows, as I have sometimes use Windows in my workplace. Or maybe one can install VirtualBox running Ubuntu to modify the data by using Linux tools. Is it possible to send command line scripts and files between Windows and Linux?

Comment: It  might, or might not, work on one PC, but likely would not be portable to another.

Comment: [Execute Shell Commands from Excel Cell](https://superuser.com/q/1220696/241386), [Running a .bat windows batch file from excel VBA](https://superuser.com/q/1216296/241386), [Call PowerShell script from Excel macro](https://superuser.com/q/724981/241386)

Comment: Why don't just use a Ubuntu as you've already done many things in it? You can use office suites in Ubuntu e.g. LibreOffice etc.

Comment: If nothing else suites your needs, there are Windows ports of Linux tools, such as the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something I have tested, but it *should* be possible.

VBA can [call](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/vba-shell) extternal programs, so you should be able to call native versions of `awk` or other UNIX-like commands. You can get these programs for a variety of [sources](https://itsfoss.com/run-linux-commands-in-windows/), such as Cygwin.